# how can i add post-categories list in elementor custom widget

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

**My control code is**
i want to create control in elementor which shows all post categories. please help me how can i achieve this...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uGUJ.png)

````
            $this->add_control(
                'show_elements',
                [
                    'label' => __( 'Post Categoris', 'plugin-domain' ),
                    'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'options' => [
                        $category,
                    ],
                    
                ]
            ); ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WP `get_categories()` to get all categories. check below code.

```
$options = array();

$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
);

$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach ( $categories as $key => $category ) {
    $options[$category->term_id] = $category->name;
}

$this->add_control(
    'show_elements',
    [
        'label' => __( 'Post Categoris', 'plugin-domain' ),
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
        'multiple' => true,
        'options' => $options,
    ]
);
```

Comment: i have used same code but in post categories showing  [object Object]

Comment: i have used same code but in post categories showing  [object Object]  https://prnt.sc/113zjrw

Comment: how can i display all posts name in select2 elementor control like this with custom post_type

Comment: Please ask a separate question about this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013427/how-can-i-display-custom-post-type-posts-list-in-elementor-select-control

Comment: @AkashPise check i answerd.