# How can i display custom post type **posts** list in elementor select control

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

How can i display custom post type **posts** list in elementor select control

**This is my code =>**
I have used this but this shows post categories not post title

```
$options = array();

    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'  => 'digital_card'
    ) );

    foreach ( $posts as $key => $post ) {
setup_postdata( $post );
$options[$post->ID] = get_the_title();
    }
    
        
        $this->add_control(
            'show_elements',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Select Posts', 'plugin-domain' ),
                'label_block' => ('bool'),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'multiple' => true,
                'options' => $options,
                
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
$options = array();

$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'  => 'digital_card'
) );

foreach ( $posts as $key => $post ) {
    $options[$post->ID] = get_the_title($post->ID);
}
```

Comment: i have used but it display post category of that post, i want to show title

Comment: how do you use it? please update in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static function getLocations()
    {
        $posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'location'));
        $allPosts = array();
        foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {

            array_push(
                    $allPosts,
                    array(
                            'map_latitude'  => $post->post_author,
                            'pin_title'     => $post->post_title,
                    )
            );

        }

        return $allPosts;
    }


$this->add_control(
                'id',
                array(
                        'label'       => __('Location Map Pins', 'textdomain'),
                        'type'        => Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
                        'default'     => Hip_Maps_Elementor_Widget::getLocations(),
                        'fields'      => $repeater->get_controls(),
                        'title_field' => '{{{ pin_title }}}',
                        'prevent_empty' => false,
                        
                )
        );
```